# Camel case pattern matching

Tags: regex

I want to make sure key Name which I had extracted from api is in valid camel case format only ,
I used following regex ^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*$ which do make sure that string start with lowerCase only , how can make sure following condition

first and last character can only be in lowercase or underscore.
No special special character including underscore is there in between first and last string index.'

Comment: Just to make sure: *"first and last character can only be in lowercase or underscore"*...do you allow a number to be at the end or not?

Comment: Do you also want to match `__` and should the match be at least 2 characters long and is aAAa also valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the following could work:

```
^(?!.+_.)[a-z_]\w*[a-z_]$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjeVhT/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?!.+_.)` - Negative lookahead to prevent an underscore other than at the start/end index.
- `[a-z_]\w*[a-z_]` - A single lowercase alpha or underscore followed by 0+ word-characters and again a single lowercase alpha or underscore.
- `$` - End line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^[a-z_][a-z]*(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9_]?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z_][a-z]*` Match one of the listed including the `_`
- `(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat an uppercase char and 1+ lowercase chars
- `[a-z0-9_]?` Optionally match one of the listed including the `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPd3qo/1)

If there should be only lowercase chars or an underscore at the end, the uppercase char should be followed by a lowercase char and you don't want to match only underscores:

```
^(?!_+$)[a-z_][a-z]*(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z_]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBbYBw/1)